# IdMappedPortTCP deactivating issue

Tags: delphi, indy10

I have one external program which doesn't support proxy to access internet and but I need proxy.

As a solution, I've written one simple Delphi Application using Indy 10.6.0.5040 and its TIdMappedPortTCP component. How it works simply,  external application connects to IdMappedPortTCP locally and IdMappedPortTCP connects to real server using my proxy settings.

To do my proxy setting, I handled OnConnect event of IdMappedPortTCP like below:

```
procedure TForm1.IdMappedPortTCP1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  io: TIdIOHandlerStack;
  proxy: TIdConnectThroughHttpProxy;

begin
  if Assigned(TIdMappedPortContext(AContext).OutboundClient) then
   begin
    io := TIdIOHandlerStack.Create(TIdMappedPortContext(AContext).OutboundClient);

    proxy := TIdConnectThroughHttpProxy.Create(io);

    proxy.Enabled := False;
    proxy.Host := FSettings.ProxyAddress;
    proxy.Port := FSettings.ProxyPort;
    proxy.Username := FSettings.ProxyUserName;
    proxy.Password := FSettings.ProxyPassword;
    If (proxy.Username <> '') or (proxy.Password <> '') then proxy.AuthorizationRequired(True);
    proxy.Enabled := True;

    io.DefaultPort := FSettings.DestinationPort[0];
    io.Port := FSettings.DestinationPort[0];
    io.Destination := FSettings.DestinationHostAddress[0];
    io.Host := FSettings.DestinationHostAddress[0];
    io.TransparentProxy := proxy;
    io.OnStatus := StackStatus;

    TIdMappedPortContext(AContext).OutboundClient.IOHandler := io;
   end;

  Log(Format('Listener connected at %s:%d', [TIdMappedPortContext(AContext).Server.MappedHost, TIdMappedPortContext(AContext).Server.MappedPort]));
end;

{ TIdConnectThroughHttpProxyHelper }

procedure TIdConnectThroughHttpProxyHelper.AuthorizationRequired(const val: boolean);
begin
  Self.FAuthorizationRequired := val;
end;

procedure TForm1.Log(const s: string);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('(%s)  %s', [FormatDateTime('hh:nn:ss:zzz', Now), s]));
end;

procedure TForm1.IdMappedPortTCP1Disconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
//  Log(Format('Listener disconnected at %s:%d', [TIdMappedPortContext(AContext).Server.MappedHost, TIdMappedPortContext(AContext).Server.MappedPort]));
end;

procedure TForm1.IdMappedPortTCP1Exception(AContext: TIdContext;
  AException: Exception);
begin
  Log(Format('Exception: %s (%s:%d)', [AException.Message,TIdMappedPortContext(AContext).Server.MappedHost, TIdMappedPortContext(AContext).Server.MappedPort]));
end;

procedure TForm1.IdMappedPortTCP1ListenException(AThread: TIdListenerThread;
  AException: Exception);
begin
  Log(Format('Listener Exception: %s', [AException.Message]));
end;

procedure TForm1.IdMappedPortTCP1OutboundConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  Log('MappedPort Destination connected.');
end;

procedure TForm1.IdMappedPortTCP1OutboundDisconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  Log('MappedPort Destination disconnected.');
end;

procedure TForm1.StackStatus(ASender: TObject;
  const AStatus: TIdStatus; const AStatusText: string);
begin
  Log(Format('Stack Status: %s', [AStatusText]));
end;
```

I have many active connections and all work flawlessly. My problem is that, if I try to deactivate IdMappedPortTCP using "IdMappedPortTCP.Active := false;" while there are active traffics, connections, it hangs there and I had to terminate delphi application using task manager.

Is there anything that I need to do manually before setting Active to false?

Thanks.

Comment: Do not call `AuthorizationRequired()` manually, let `TIdConnectThroughHttpProxy` handle that. And you do not need to set any `TIdIOHandlerStack` properties other than `TransparentProxy` and `OnStatus`, let `TIdTCPClient` handle that.

Comment: Hi Remy, FAuthorizationRequired of proxy by default is false when it is created. It always tries accessing proxy without authentication first, and then realized that it has to use user name, password and tries again. To skip first step, I wrote a helper function to force it authenticate always. OnStatus event is just to report status on a Memo (I added all functions to the question). While debugging, I found something related to my problem. If I use Memo1 in OnMappedPortDisconnect event, it cause my program to hang at deactivation time. But if I comment that line, seems everything is perfect.

Comment: `FAuthorizationRequired` is an internal variable, do not mess with it. It is always false by default, and then set to true temporarily if the `IOHandler` needs to be closed and reopened because the proxy sent a `407` reply with a `Connection: close` or `Proxy-Connection: close` response header. Reopening the `IOHandler` causes `MakeConnection()` to be called again while it is already running, so `FAuthorizationRequired` is used to detect that second connect so a `Proxy-Authorization` request header is added to the new request.

Comment: Delaying authorization until the second connect is intentional.  Not all proxies require authorization, so `TIdConnectThroughHttpProxy` does not send authorization unless the proxy explicitly asks for it. `TIdHTTP` works the same way.

Comment: Indy servers are multi-threaded. The `OnConnect` and `OnDisconnect` events are triggered in the context of a worker thread, not the main UI thread. As such, you must sync with the main thread, such as with the `TThread.Synchronize()` or `TThread.Queue()` methods, or Indy's `TIdSync` or `TIdNotify` classes, in order to access UI components safely. If the main thread is deactivating the server, an asynchronous approach (`TThread.Queue()` or `TIdNotify`) is preferred over a synchronous one (`TThread.Synchronize()` or `TIdSync`) to avoid a deadlock.

Comment: Thanks for explanation Remy. I can accept your comment if you make it answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indy servers are multi-threaded. Their events (like `OnConnect`, `OnDisconnect`, `OnExecute`, `OnException`, and `OnListenException`) are triggered in the context of worker threads, not the context of the main UI thread. As such, you must sync with the main thread, such as with the `TThread.Synchronize()` or `TThread.Queue()` methods, or Indy's `TIdSync` or `TIdNotify` classes, in order to access UI components safely.

If the main thread is busy deactivating the server, it cannot process sync requests, so an asynchronous approach (`TThread.Queue()` or
`TIdNotify`) is preferred over a synchronous one (`TThread.Synchronize()` or `TIdSync`) to avoid a deadlock.  Alternatively, deactivate the server in a worker thread so the main thread is free to process sync requests.